# How to generate nested JSON responce using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have four tables, ALBUM,ARTIST,SONG,GENRES

ALBUM (ID(PK),ALBUM_NAME,ARTIST_ID(FK),GENRES_ID(FK),ALBUM_POSTER)
SONG (ID(PK),SONG_NAME,ALBUM_ID(FK),ARTIST_ID(FK),SONG_LOCATION)
ARTIST (ID(PK),ARTIST_NAME)
GENRES (ID(PK), GENRES_NAME)

I have created the bellow php file in order to create json file as "desired output" shows, but I have got "actual output" as bellow shows. All songs from all albums are included in each album "song_detail" section as the actual output shows.

**php**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ALBUM_ID, ALBUM_NAME,ARTIST_NAME,GENRES_NAME,ALBUM_POSTER "
    . "FROM ALBUM,ARTIST,SONG,GENRES "
    . "WHERE ALBUM.ID=SONG.ALBUM_ID AND SONG.ARTIST_ID=ARTIST.ID AND GENRES.ID=ALBUM.GENRES_ID";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$response["albums"] = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{   
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {   $album = array();  
        $album["album_id"] = $row["ALBUM_ID"];
        $album["album_name"] = $row["ALBUM_NAME"];
        $album["artist_name"] = $row["ARTIST_NAME"];
        $album["genres_name"] = $row["GENRES_NAME"];
        $album["album_poster"] = "http://www.".$row["ALBUM_POSTER"];
        $album['song_details'] = array();

        $sql2 = "SELECT*"
        . " FROM SONG,ALBUM where SONG.ALBUM_ID = ALBUM.ID";
        $result2 = $db->query($sql2);
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
        {       
            $album['song_details'][] = array(
            'songName' => $row2["SONG_NAME"],
            'song_location' => "http://www.".$row2["SONG_LOCATION"]);
        }
        array_push($response["albums"], $album);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
}
```

**desired output**

```
[
{
    "album_name": "Startboy",
    "artist_name": "Weeknd",
    "genres_name":"R&B",
    "album_poster": "www.yyy.storage.x.png",
    "songs_details": [{
            "title": "False Alarm",
            "song_location": "www././../yw.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "Reminder",
            "song_location": "www././../x.mp3"
        }

    ]
}, 
{
    "album_name": "25",
    "artist_name": "Adele",
    "genres_name":"",
    "album_poster": "www.yyy.storage.a.png",
    "songs_details": [{
            "title": "Hello",
            "song_location": "www././../yy.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "I Miss You",
            "song_location": "www././../yx.mp3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

**Actual output**

```
[
{
    "album_name": "Startboy",
    "artist_name": "Weeknd",
    "genres_name":"R&B",
    "album_poster": "www.yyy.storage.x.png",
    "songs_details": [{
            "title": "False Alarm",
            "song_location": "www././../yw.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "Reminder",
            "song_location": "www././../x.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "Hello",
            "song_location": "www././../yy.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "I Miss You",
            "song_location": "www././../yx.mp3"
    }]
}, 
{
    "album_name": "25",
    "artist_name": "Adele",
    "genres_name":"",
    "album_poster": "www.yyy.storage.a.png",
    "songs_details": [{
            "title": "False Alarm",
            "song_location": "www././../y.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "Reminder",
            "song_location": "www././../x.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "Hello",
            "song_location": "www././../yy.mp3"
        },
        {
            "title": "I Miss You",
            "song_location": "www././../yx.mp3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are selecting the songs, your SQL doesn't limit which album the tracks are from (although it does make sure they match the ALBUM)...

```
$sql2 = "SELECT*"
. " FROM SONG,ALBUM where SONG.ALBUM_ID = ALBUM.ID";
```

You need to just pick the SONG records according to the current album...

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM SONG where ID =".$row["ALBUM_ID"];
```

You could use prepared statements here, but as this is using a field from another table it can be used - but not essential.

Comment: Thank you Nigel. It now works $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM SONG where SONG.ALBUM_ID =".$row["ALBUM_ID"];